# How do I make my ItemsControl items appear in a staggered wrap

Tags: wpf

The code below gives me a grid of items, even though each item is naturally of a different height.  Supposedly I'm supposed to set the height of something, but I don't know what that thing is, or where I get the value I need.

```
I want    I get
a  c      a c
a  c      a c
a  d      a .
b  d      b d
b  d      b d
          . d
```

code:

```
      <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}" Margin="20,0,0,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel 
                       Orientation="vertical" <!-- edit: adding this line solved it -->
                     />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <W3V:ControlChooser Content="{Binding}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item order does not need to be left-to-right, then changing [`WrapPanel.Orientation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.orientation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be enough.

**Edit:** Just tested it and it works as i expected:

[image]

Underlying code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200px"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: It looks like he's getting the order he wants, just not the positioning.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: Given that the items are transpositionally symmetrical it's hard to tell what the intended order is. Maybe the order does not even matter.

Comment: I think those numbers are Item Heights (including the dots under them), as if arranged on a 2 x 5 grid.  It seems like he's trying to get uneven rows, but it's cleanly breaking them so that each row is top aligned, leaving space above if that item is shorter than the row.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: I know, but as i said: If you transpose that layout you end up with the same result, i.e. item 2 and 3 are switched but they both have size 2, so we don't know if they changed order or not.

Comment: The order of items is fixed.  Think of it like a multi-column newspaper article with paragraphs that individually are not supposed to be split across columns.  Please don't consider the numbers, those only indicate the heights of each item, not the content.

Comment: and I'm not looking for horizontal, I want vertical wrapping.  Sorry the ascii is unclear.  Maybe if I edit it to use repeated letters it will be clearer?

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: I don't get how you end up with your layout, works just fine for me (see edit).

Comment: hm, you're right.  It seems I screwed up asking the question, misunderstanding what I had written.